# Automate AI model training and create endpoint whenever the train data is updated using aws Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am searching for good references(videos or texts) to automate my AI (custom NLP model) training job whenever I update my data in s3 bucket i..e, whenever my pipeline detects change in data, it starts training automatically and create the endpoint. I am currently using aws API gateway and lambda to communicate with the endpoint. However, for each time I update my train data, I need to run the training job manually to create new endpoint. I want to automate the later part.
Is there anyone in this group who can help me with the relevant resources to achieve this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Automated training can be achieved with [Sagemaker Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pipelines/).
There are different [approaches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html) possible.